# How to change yum install location?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, yum

Could anyone tell me how to change yum install default directory? I have been trying to install datastax cassandra after creating the datastax.repo file in yum.repos.d directory but when installing it says no enough space. it is installing in default / file system. can i change to /data or /local/apps directory where there is plenty of space. how can i do this. commands  used:  yum install dse-full;

many thanks for the help

Comment: or you can use the tarball and place it anywhere -- http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/install/installTARdse.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Not really.

**If** the RPM is built as a relocatable RPM (almost none are that I'm aware of). Then, and only then, you can use the `--prefix` or `--relocate` arguments to `rpm` to do some amount of prefix replacement/path translation.

That said that is almost certainly not the case.

**If** the rpm installs to under a specific prefix (e.g. `/opt/cassandra`) then you might be able to create a symlink at that location to your other partitions and that might work.

A better option (and one that might be more reliable) would be to use a bind mount at that location to somewhere on your other partition.

That said the real answer here is to give your root partition more space. Which, assuming you used `LVM` to create your partitions (and you really probably should) is not a complicated task.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on a legacy server with insufficient disk space, and had to use an approach similar to this answer.

You can find out where it wants to install to using `rpm` commands:

```
rpm -q -p -l /path/to/rpmfile.rpm |less
```

If it installs under a common directory such as /usr/local/, you're in luck. I cannot download the RPMs from the vendor, since it requires registration, but from the [docs about the *.run* installer](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/install/installSilent.html) for the same product, the default is `/usr/local/dse`.

If this is the same for the *.rpm* installs, then you can just symlink that directory to your large disk:

```
ln -s /usr/local/dse /local/apps/dse
```

Hope that helps!